# Comparing multiple dataframes to find differing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list, where each element is a Pandas dataframe. Each dataframe consists of the same number of rows and has two columns, `Parameter` and `Value`. One element looks like -

```
Parameter   Value
0   Mode:   GDR-Eth
1   Regtest:    //acds/main/
2   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
... ... ...
539 tx_ipg_size_gui 12
540 tx_max_frame_size_gui   1518
541 tx_vlan_detection_gui   1
542 txmac_saddr_gui 73588229205
543 xcvr_type   FGT
```

I want to parse the entire list, and display the parameter and each value when they are not the same across all the dataframes. How can I do so?

Comment: So you want all of the unique parameter:value pairs across all the dataframes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah that's it. I just want to see how the values vary across the dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of dataframes of the same structure, with some information repeating:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

li = [
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Parameter": np.random.choice(["foo", "bar", "baz"], size=100),
            "Value": np.random.randint(0, 20, size=100),
        }
    )
    for n in range(10)
]
```

We can get the unique information in them all like this:

```
pd.concat(li).drop_duplicates().dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting a lot of NaNs in my resultant array

Comment: edited to add a `dropna` call

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat(li).rename_axis(“row”).reset_index().groupby(“row”)[[“Parameter”, “Value”]].value_counts()
```

That will tell you how many unique parameter/value pairs you have on each row (across all dataframes). If there was only one unique pair (common to all), then the count will be len(li).